# How can I disable the laptop keyboard in tty and then after a time turn it on again?

Tags: debian, keyboard, tty

I have a kind of old ASUS Eee 1000HE PC and I replaced Windows 7 with Debian 32 Bit (PC is 32 bit).

And now I use it a lot because I always wanted Linux on a laptop

But I have one problem: some of the laptop's built-in keyboard are stuck so they send random keypresses when I turn the machine on.  I already know more or less how to fix it, but until then I'll use an external keyboard. Only my question is, how do I turn off the built-in keyboard and then when the keyboard is fixed, turn it on?
I don't use any X sessions, I just use TTY. I searched the Internet, but it only shows me, X sessions, not TTY

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to disable it? If you plug in an external keyboard, then both the external and the on-board keyboards will work at the same time. If you don't want to use the laptop's keyboard, all you have to do is not use it and only use the external one. Why would you also need to disable it?

Comment: There could be some stuck keys - until very recently I had Eee 700 in a very similar situation, with `a` and `s` keys permanently pressed (not physically stuck, but perhaps shorted somewhere on the mainboard, the notebook has been badly beaten), and I was using it happily as a media player with a remote control and the internal keyboard disabled in software

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, May be. When i start my pc and starts linux, it starts pressing random keys repeatly, only when i do backspace it stops and inits to TTY

What i need to do is maybe open my pc and see what is happening...

Comment: @terdon Is because when i start linux, it starts pressing a random key repeatly and it bugs my pc a little....

Comment: Ah, OK I see. Yeah, that would be annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reasonably modern distribution (i.e. not period specific for the laptop).

1. locate the input device corresponding to the keyboard, e.g. by checking `ls -l /dev/input/by-id/`
2. run `evtest --grab /dev/input/event1 >/dev/null` (if the device is `event1`)

As long as the `evtest` is running, internal keyboard won't be relayed to the user interface.

Comment: It didn't worked... It run the command without outputs but the internal keyboard it stills work and sometime it starts pressing random keys AND THAT VERY VERY ANNOYING!! sorry. And Thanks to trying to help....

Comment: @Devilas are you sure your are using the right device? You can try all of them,  one by one... (and delete the /dev/null redirection to see some useful output)

Comment: Ok, il try them all

Comment: I tried all of them and only the external keyboard worked with that command, but the internal it didn't....